# How to serialize a form where name is different than data structure

Tags: reactjs, forms, post, serialization

How can I serialize a form whose data structute is different to it's name.

For example, I have following form, which is getting `numberofItems` from `inventory` object and displaying in a TextArea.

```
<Form
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={{
        numberofItems: inventories.numberofItems
    }}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
<FormItem
    name={'numberofItems'}
    label={'Current Stock'}
    maxLength={32000}
>
    {inputProps => <TextArea {...inputProps} />}
</FormItem>
</Form>
```

This works fine when rendering the form. But when I try to post the form, the expected property is null. Because, the service expects `inventories.numberofItems` where as I am sending `numberofItems` , as per it's name.

I can avoid this by doing passing the object to form and extracting each field to control.

```
<Form
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={{
        inventories: inventories
    }}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
<FormItem
    name={'inventories.numberofItems'}
    label={'Current Stock'}
    maxLength={32000}
>
    {inputProps => <TextArea {...inputProps} />}
</FormItem>
</Form>
```

But is there a way I can serialize a control, with a different key from it's name.

In my case, I want to serialize the form with `inventories.numberofItems` while keeping the name of the control as `numberofItems`.

```
<FormItem
    name={'numberofItems'}
    label={'Current Stock'}
    maxLength={32000}
>
    {inputProps => <TextArea {...inputProps} />}
</FormItem>
```

Comment: what form library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in order to successfully submit the form (I don't know if it fits your needs though, this is what I do in similar cases in my code where I have JAX-RS backend which cannot map to unknown properties of object) is set the required property and delete the one that cannot be submitted.

```
function handleSubmit(myFormObject) {
  myFormObject.inventories = {numberofItems: myFormObject.numberofItems}
  delete myFormObject.numberofItems
  .
  .
  .
}
```

`redux-form` supports such cases though. You can define a `Field` with property `name` being a "compound" one and it will properly map to your form object being submitted.

Check [this sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-lg426)

```
      <Field name="test.notes" component="textarea" />
```

Comment: Ok, this what we have to handle on submission. I was expecting more in terms of setting  another property on control it self (if it does exist).

Comment: @Simsons I don't know what form library you are using but `redux-form` supports it. I added a link to a small sandbox project featuring this functionality.

Comment: Yep , in your example , I want to serialize as test.notes while keeping the name as notes itself,  <Field name="notes" component="textarea" />

Comment: hmm not sure, I thought this was OK since it "solved" the first part of your question, meanings that now object will not be null since it is correctly mapped to `Field`. To be honest, since this works I haven't been into thoughts about cputting my own names in properties since this is confusing.